# How to subset a dataframe based on matches with another dataframe?

Tags: r

I want to write a for loop (or similar) whereby if `df.1a`, `df.2a`, `df.3a` corresponds with `subtypes$clust`, I want to subset the `exp.df` data frame.

```
df.1a <- exp.df[colnames(exp.df) %in% rownames(subtypes),] && subtypes[subtypes$clust=="1a",]
df.2a <- exp.df[colnames(exp.df) %in% rownames(subtypes),] && subtypes[subtypes$clust=="2a",]
df.1b <- exp.df[colnames(exp.df) %in% rownames(subtypes),] && subtypes[subtypes$clust=="1b",]
df.2b <- exp.df[colnames(exp.df) %in% rownames(subtypes),] && subtypes[subtypes$clust=="2b",]
```

Traceback:

```
Error in exp[colnames(exp.df) %in% rownames(subtypes), ] && subtypes[subtypes$clust ==  : 
  invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

Data:

`exp.df`

```
> dput(exp.df[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A = c(7.65342121905285, 6.35598354101006, 
14.3511850042327, 10.3737643425674, 10.0819596419255), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A = c(5.09389393824392, 
6.93597002271109, 12.4136523086721, 11.1918237390263, 10.1912122382252
), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A = c(4.70168212029528, 7.54694769203808, 10.1689338100564, 
9.96839262629172, 9.87305770150294), TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A = c(7.99645936536463, 
6.89258167250936, 13.6832285748428, 10.3714563849361, 10.4176870383992
), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A = c(5.13719199914349, 6.92859654071157, 12.0367193976262, 
10.8202555636581, 10.3262700402849)), row.names = c("A1BG", "A2LD1", 
"A2M", "A4GALT", "AAAS"), class = "data.frame")
```

`subtypes`

```
> dput(subtypes[1:5,])

structure(list(clust = c("1a", "2a", "2b", "1b", "2a", row.names = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output:

`df.1a`

```
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A = c(7.65342121905285, 6.35598354101006, 
14.3511850042327, 10.3737643425674, 10.0819596419255), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A = c(5.09389393824392, 
6.93597002271109, 12.4136523086721, 11.1918237390263, 10.1912122382252
)), row.names = c("A1BG", "A2LD1", 
"A2M", "A4GALT", "AAAS"), class = "data.frame")
```

`df.2a`

```
structure(list(TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A = c(4.70168212029528, 7.54694769203808, 10.1689338100564, 
9.96839262629172, 9.87305770150294), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A = c(5.13719199914349, 6.92859654071157, 12.0367193976262, 
10.8202555636581, 10.3262700402849)), row.names = c("A1BG", "A2LD1", 
"A2M", "A4GALT", "AAAS"), class = "data.frame")
```

`df.1b`

```
structure(TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A = c(7.99645936536463, 
6.89258167250936, 13.6832285748428, 10.3714563849361, 10.4176870383992
), row.names = c("A1BG", "A2LD1", 
"A2M", "A4GALT", "AAAS"), class = "data.frame")
```

`df.2b`

```
structure(TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A = c(4.70168212029528, 7.54694769203808, 10.1689338100564, 
9.96839262629172, 9.87305770150294)), row.names = c("A1BG", "A2LD1", 
"A2M", "A4GALT", "AAAS"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @SamR I've added the expected output and change the exp() name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `&&`

The [`&&`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html) operator is a logical operator. It expects a `TRUE` / `FALSE` value on either side (or a value that can be coerced to logical, e.g. `0` / `1`). You use it here:

```r
exp.df[colnames(exp.df) %in% rownames(subtypes),] && subtypes[subtypes$clust=="1a",]
```

You cannot coerce a `data.frame` to `TRUE` or `FALSE`, so this does not work. Also `&&` is not an element-wise operator, so e.g. `c(TRUE, FALSE) && TRUE` returns `TRUE`, rather than recycling the second vector and returning `c(TRUE, FALSE)`, which the single `&` operator would do.

### base R solution

It looks like you are trying to subset the columns of `exp.df` where they match the row names of the `subtypes` data.frame where `clust=="1a"`. You could write this subset operation like this:

```r
exp.df[, 
    colnames(exp.df) %in% rownames(subtypes[subtypes$clust=="1a",,drop=FALSE]), 
drop=FALSE]
```

Note the `drop=FALSE`. Without this, as the data.frame is only one column, R simplifies it to a vector, and you lose the row names. You can instead subset all the `rownames` into a list and iterate over that list with `lapply()`:

```r
# Create a list of groups
col_groups <- split(rownames(subtypes), subtypes$clust)

df_list <- lapply(
    col_groups,
    \(grp) 
    exp.df[, names(exp.df) %in% grp, drop = FALSE]
)
```

This has the advantage of storing all the resulting data frames in a list that is easy to iterate over and subset

```r
names(df_list)
# "1a" "1b" "2a" "2b"

# subsetting
df_list[["2a"]]
#    TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A
#               <num>            <num>
# 1:         5.093894         5.137192
# 2:         6.935970         6.928597
# 3:        12.413652        12.036719
# 4:        11.191824        10.820256
# 5:        10.191212        10.326270
```

### Creating objects in the global environment

If you do need to bring the items back into the global environment (which, if you have many data frames in a list, is generally not a good idea), you can do:

```r
# Make sure names don't start with numbers, e.g. `1a`, `2a`
names(df_list)  <- paste0("exp.", names(df_list))
list2env(df_list, envir = globalenv())
exp.2a
#    TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A
#               <num>            <num>
# 1:         5.093894         5.137192
# 2:         6.935970         6.928597
# 3:        12.413652        12.036719
# 4:        11.191824        10.820256
# 5:        10.191212        10.326270
```

### data.table approach

I don't like having to think about `drop = FALSE`. Instead, I would use the `data.table` package for this:

```r
# Load package and make each data.frame into a data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(subtypes, keep.rownames = TRUE)
setDT(exp.df)
```

```r
col_groups  <- split(subtypes$rn, subtypes$clust)

df_list  <- lapply(col_groups,
    \(grp)
    exp.df[, ..grp]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach in which we loop over the `subtypes` `data.frame` by group, select columns accordingly and write those `data.frame`s to the global environment:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

# convert rownames to columns
exp.df2   <- tibble::rownames_to_column(exp.df, "type")
subtypes2 <- tibble::rownames_to_column(subtypes, "col")

subtypes2 %>% 
  group_by(clust) %>% 
  group_walk(~ semi_join(.x, tibble(col = colnames(exp.df2))) %>%
                 {select(exp.df2, all_of(.$col))} %>% 
               {env_bind(globalenv(), !! sym(paste0("df.", .y$clust)) := .)}
              
  )

# example data.frame 
df.1a
#>   TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A
#> 1         7.653421
#> 2         6.355984
#> 3        14.351185
#> 4        10.373764
#> 5        10.081960
```

Data from the OP

```r
exp.df <- structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A = c(7.65342121905285, 6.35598354101006, 
                                    14.3511850042327, 10.3737643425674, 10.0819596419255), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A = c(5.09389393824392, 
                                                                                                                6.93597002271109, 12.4136523086721, 11.1918237390263, 10.1912122382252
                                    ), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A = c(4.70168212029528, 7.54694769203808, 10.1689338100564, 
                                                            9.96839262629172, 9.87305770150294), TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A = c(7.99645936536463, 
                                                                                                                      6.89258167250936, 13.6832285748428, 10.3714563849361, 10.4176870383992
                                                            ), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A = c(5.13719199914349, 6.92859654071157, 12.0367193976262, 
                                                                                    10.8202555636581, 10.3262700402849)), row.names = c("A1BG", "A2LD1", 
                                                                                                                                        "A2M", "A4GALT", "AAAS"), class = "data.frame")



subtypes <- structure(list(clust = c("1a", "2a", "2b", "1b", "2a")),
               row.names = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A"),
               class = "data.frame")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>